# What is "prolog style" in Scala?

Tags: scala, prolog, implicit, scala-3

The Scala 3 reference at https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html mentions some "Prolog-like programming style" possible with Scala 3 mataprogramming:

> The problem so far was that the Prolog-like programming style of
> implicit search becomes viral: Once some construct depends on implicit
> search it has to be written as a logic program itself.

> But they all keep the viral nature of implicit search programs based
> on logic programming.

I did some search but understood only that it somehow abuses the Scala compile-time behavior, and that something in it resembles Prolog.

What is that "Prolog-like programming style" and how it works? What namely resembles Prolog? Does it work in Scala 3?

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't "abuse Scala's compile time behavior", the essence of Scala *is this compile time behavior*. The whole point of the `given`s is that instead of writing out tons of boilerplate manually, it gives you the programmable term inference machinery which can generate all the boilerplate for you.

Not entirely incidentally, this term inference machinery looks a little like Prolog (because on a high enough abstraction level, even your teacup looks like a Prolog program).

Here is a basic correspondence to get you started:

- Prolog-**Atoms** correspond to ordinary **types**.
- Prolog-**Variables** correspond to **type parameters**.
- What's [called "**Functors**" here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Data_types) corresponds to **type constructors**.
- Stating **facts** corresponds to providing **constant `given`s**.
- Making **queries** corresponds to **`summon`ing** corresponding proof-terms.

Let's start with a very simple example where we have just one atom, one prolog-"functor", one fact, and one query: this [example from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Rules_and_facts)

```
cat(tom).
?- cat(tom).
>> Yes
```

can be directly translated into

```
trait Tom     // Atom 'Tom'
trait Cat[X]  // Functor 'Cat' with arity = 1

// Fact: cat(tom).
given Cat[Tom] with {}

// Query: ?- cat(tom). (is Tom a Cat?)
val query = summon[Cat[Tom]] // type-checks = Yes
```

Prolog *rules* correspond to parameterized `given`-definitions, the antecedents on the right side correspond to the `using`-parameters in the parameter list. For example, the classical [syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism) example expressed in Prolog as

```
man(socrates).
mortal(X) :- man(X).
?- mortal(socrates).
>> True
```

can be encoded with a parameterized `given` that uses `Man[X]` and produces a proof of `Mortal[X]`:

```
trait Socrates
trait Man[X]
trait Mortal[X]

given socratesIsAMan: Man[Socrates] with {}
given allMenAreMortal[X](using m: Man[X]): Mortal[X] with {}

val query = summon[Mortal[Socrates]]
```

You can use `scala3-compiler -Xprint:typer` to see the composite proof term that the compiler generated to prove that `Socrates` is `Mortal`:

```
allMenAreMortal[Socrates](socratesIsAMan)
```

Knowing how to encode rules allows you to encode the more complicated [example from the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Execution):

```
mother_child(trude, sally).
 
father_child(tom, sally).
father_child(tom, erica).
father_child(mike, tom).
 
sibling(X, Y)      :- parent_child(Z, X), parent_child(Z, Y).
 
parent_child(X, Y) :- father_child(X, Y).
parent_child(X, Y) :- mother_child(X, Y).

?- sibling(sally, erica).
>> Yes
```

as follows:

```
trait Trude
trait Sally
trait Tom
trait Erica
trait Mike

trait FatherChild[F, C]
trait MotherChild[M, C]
trait ParentChild[P, C]
trait Sibling[X, Y]

given MotherChild[Trude, Sally] with {}
given FatherChild[Tom, Sally] with {}
given FatherChild[Tom, Erica] with {}
given FatherChild[Mike, Tom] with {}
given [X, Y, Z](using pczx: ParentChild[Z, X], pczy: ParentChild[Z, Y])
  : Sibling[X, Y] with {}

given fatherhoodImpliesParentship[X, Y](using fc: FatherChild[X, Y])
  : ParentChild[X, Y] with {}

given motherhoodImpliesParentship[X, Y](using mc: MotherChild[X, Y])
  : ParentChild[X, Y] with {}

val query = summon[Sibling[Erica, Sally]] // Yes
```

Here, the compiler will generate a proof term that explains that `Erica` and `Sally` are `Sibling`s because they have the same father `Tom`:

```
given_Sibling_X_Y[Erica, Sally, Tom](
  fatherhoodImpliesParentship[Tom, Erica](given_FatherChild_Tom_Erica),
  fatherhoodImpliesParentship[Tom, Sally](given_FatherChild_Tom_Sally)
)
```

More generally, conjunctions are encoded by multiple `using`-parameters, and disjunctions are encoded by multiple `givens` with the same result type:

```
// We can write "X /\ Y" as infix operator for conjunction
case class /\[A, B](a: A, b: B)

// We can write "X \/ Y" as infix operator for disjunctions
enum \/[+A, +B]:
  case Inl(a: A)
  case Inr(b: B)

// Inference for conjunctions: multiple parameters in `using`
given [A, B](using a:A, b: B): (A /\ B) = /\(a, b)

// Inference for disjunctions: multiple rules
given [A](using a: A): \/[A, Nothing] = \/.Inl(a)
given [B](using b: B): \/[Nothing, B] = \/.Inr(b)

// Example:
trait X
trait Y
trait Z
trait W
given X with { override def toString = "X" }
given W with { override def toString = "W" }

@main def query(): Unit =
  println(summon[(X \/ Y) /\ (Z \/ W)])
  // Finds a proof and prints `/\(Inl(X), Inr(W))`.
```

Since Scala 3, there is even negation available through `util.NotGiven`:

```
import scala.util.NotGiven

trait X
trait Y
trait /\[X, Y]

given X with {}
given [A, B](using a: A, b: B): /\[A, B] with {}

// Fails if we add `given Y with {}`
val query = summon[X /\ NotGiven[Y]]
```

Scala 3 adds a whole bunch of stuff on top of that, such as [tuples](https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/02/26/tuples-bring-generic-programming-to-scala-3.html) (which are basically type-level lists) or [computing with numeric / boolean / string singleton types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html#the-scalacompiletimeops-package), but I don't want to go too deeply into the details here.

Instead, I'd like to conclude by briefly sketching how it all fits into the landscape. The interesting difference between Prolog and Scala's type system is that the Scala compiler actually generates *proof terms*, and unlike in Prolog (where you get a simple "Yes"/"No"), those proof terms can carry around arbitrarily complicated computational content.

You might have noticed that in the examples above, the `with {}` mostly remained empty. This is usually not the case in the real code, quite the contrary: in the real code, you usually have some non-trivial definitions in the body of every  `given ... with { ... }`. The reason why one is writing all those facts and inference rules is not for solving logical puzzles and obtaining "Yes" / "No" answers, but for generating huge complicated proof terms that *do useful stuff*.

The way it works is usually as follows:

- Suppose you want to obtain a thing `X`
- You import some big-&-smart library that knows how to construct a variety of things similar to the desired `X`
- You use the "predicates" ( = typeclasses) / facts / rules ( = givens) of that library to express very precisely the properties that you want the thing `X` to have
- If your description is precise enough, the library & the Scala compiler is able to summon the thing `X` purely from its type description.

So, in your average programming language, you have to write out all the terms manually. In Scala 3, you can instead specify the desired properties of the desired term through types, and the compiler will use this Prolog-like term inference system to summon a term with the right properties (given the right libraries, that is).

Comment: Is it possible to know *how* the result was achieved? If you ask Prolog, "Can I make a breakfast with what I've got in the friger?" it will answer `Yes`, while you most likely expect either "take this, this, and this, and do this" or even actually making a breakfast after you approve what it proposed, to e.g. filter out recipes that require too much time. You mentioned something like this in "The way it works..." part. How does the code look?

Comment: @18446744073709551615 You can use `-Xprint:typer` to show the "desugared" tree, with all the typeclass instances already inferred. I've added some of the proof-terms.

Comment: There is no "filter out recipes" option, though: there is either exactly one solution, or there is none (including the case when the compiler exits with an error message about ambiguity). There is always at most one item on the menu: *the correct one*.

Comment: I am thinking about something like this:

print_file(X:Filename) :- read(X,Representation), print(Representation).
read(X:Filename, CollectionOfLines[X]) :- { read_lines(X) }.
read(X:Filename, String[X]) :- { slurp_file(X) }.
print(X:String) :- { println(X) }.
print(X:CollectionOfLines) :- { X.foreach(println)}.

given Filename("foo.txt")
val howto = summon[print_file]
howto.apply()

I expect such kind of program to print the specified file. But so far I do not know how to specify the procedural part.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 That seems like 1. a rather atypical use case 2. too long for the comment section. I think you should ask it as a separate question.

Comment: as a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73625638/prolog-style-in-scala-mixing-with-procedural-code