# Scala 3: defining custom control structures

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-3

I want to define my own *C++-17-like* `if` statement. (It's an exercise in metaprogramming.)
I easily could define:

```
inline def xif[T](inline cond: Boolean)(inline body: T) = if cond then body
```

and/or

```
def yif[T](cond: Boolean)(body: => T) = if cond then body
```

so that these three definitions output the same numbers:

```
def testxif =
  for i <- 0 until 10 do
    xif {val j = i*3; j%2==0} {println(i)}

def testyif =
  for i <- 0 until 10 do
    yif {val j = i*3; j%2==0} {println(i)}

def testif =
  for i <- 0 until 10 do
    if ({val j = i*3; j%2==0}) {println(i)}
```

It is remarkable that `xif` and `if` generate the same code, good job, Scala! (The inline parameter is indeed inlined, while the "by-name" parameter (marked with "equals-greater" `=>`) is invoked as a lambda.)

```
public void testxif() {
    .MODULE$.until$extension(scala.Predef..MODULE$.intWrapper(0), 10).foreach((i) -> {
        int j = i * 3;
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            scala.Predef..MODULE$.println(BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(i));
        }

    });
}

public void testyif() {
    .MODULE$.until$extension(scala.Predef..MODULE$.intWrapper(0), 10).foreach((i) -> {
        int j = i * 3;
        this.yif(j % 2 == 0, () -> {
            this.testyif$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1(i);
            return BoxedUnit.UNIT;
        });
    });
}

public void testif() {
    .MODULE$.until$extension(scala.Predef..MODULE$.intWrapper(0), 10).foreach((i) -> {
        int j = i * 3;
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            scala.Predef..MODULE$.println(BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(i));
        }

    });
}

private final void testyif$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1(final int i$1) {
    scala.Predef..MODULE$.println(BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(i$1));
}
```

I could easily define `ifElse`, but this would be rather lame. I want an optional `xelse` part, probably on the next line.

And I want values defined in the *if* part to be visible in the *then* part. In C++ 17, we can write:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if(int j=i*3; j%2==0) {
      printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
    }
  }
}
```

(note that `j` is defined in the `if` part)

But in Scala 3 this does not work, neither with my current `xif` nor with the out-of-box `if`:

```
def testxif2 =
  for i <- 0 until 10 do
    xif {val j = i*3; j%2==0} {println(i + " " + j)}
//                                               ^
//                                               Not found: j
```

***Questions:***

Given all this Scala-3 metaprogramming,

1. How do I implement an ***optional*** `else` part? (Let us call it `xelse`)
2. How do I make the values defined in the `if` part visible in the `then` and `else` parts?

Comment: "It is remarkable that xif and if generate the same code" - your `xif` does an `if` inside it's body, so what did you expect to generate?!

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip _"what did you expect"_ -- just anything. `yif` also could be reduced to the same code, but it was not.

Comment: The second one is impossible without getting into a macro which hoists the val into a var in the enclosing scope, as the language definition pretty firmly states that a val defined in a block is only scoped within that block.

Comment: You could have something like `xif { i * 3 } { _ % 2 == 0 } { j => println(i + " " + j) }`, but that's not exactly what you're looking for, probably especially around inlining.